# Is there a simple way to export/import firewalld settings?

Tags: centos7, firewalld

Is there a simple way to export/import firewalld settings? I'd like to set firewalld on one server an then use the same for a lot of others. Including adding custom zones, direct rules etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firewalld stores its configuration in `/etc/firewalld` and within that directory you can find various configuration files:

- `firewalld.conf` provides overall configuration.
- Files in the `zones` directory provide your custom firewall rules for each zone.
- Files in the `services` directory provide custom services you have defined.
- Files in the `icmptypes` directory provide custom icmptypes you have defined.

There is a matching directory structure in `/usr/lib/firewalld` which provides the *defaults* for zones, services and icmptypes, in case you want to start customizing from a template, or simply see what the files look like.

The firewall configuration of the main services (ftp, httpd, etc) comes in the `/usr/lib/firewalld/services` directory. But it is still possible to add new ones in the `/etc/firewalld/services` directory. Also, if files exist at both locations for the same service, the file in the `/etc/firewalld/services` directory takes precedence.

Comment: Just to add to this - if SELinux is enabled you'll need to fix the permissions on the files if you copy from one server to another.