# How to load iptables rules to firewalld?

Tags: iptables, firewalld

I've got centos 6 running server. It uses iptables. I want to migrate to centos 7. Centos 7 uses firewalld. 
My aim is to download iptables configuration(rules) and apply to firewalld.
I can download iptables rules like this:

```
iptables-save
```

I don't know how to apply `iptables-save`'s output to firewalld. I hope there is automated way.
**Question:** How can I apply current iptables rules to firewalld? I don't like to configure manually because there might be many server with big iptables rules/configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is the RHEL 6 --> 7 [migration planning guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/migration_planning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-migration_planning_guide-security_and_access_control) but in short:

- If you configured your RHEL/CentOS 6 firewall with `system-config-firewall`, you can use the `firewall-offline-cmd` tool to migrate the configuration from `/etc/sysconfig/system-config-firewall` into the default zone of firewalld.
- If you used any other method to configure your current firewall there is, as far as I know, no practical migration to firewalld and your options are:

  - either create a new configuration with firewall-cmd or firewall-config
  - disable firewalld and continue to use the old iptables and ip6tables services. That allows you to keep the existing firewall rules. Copy the `iptables-save` export and load it with iptables-restore. See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-using_iptables

Comment: The first link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Inside SSH CentOS 6 execute these commands :

```
sudo iptables-save > iptables-export

cat iptables-export

scp iptables-export user@server_b_ip_address:/tmp
```

Firewalld stores its configuration in `/etc/firewalld` and within that directory you can find various configuration files:

- `firewalld.conf` provides overall configuration.
- Files in the `zones` directory provide your custom firewall rules for each zone.
- Files in the `services` directory provide custom services you have defined.
- Files in the `icmptypes` directory provide custom icmptypes you have defined.

There is a matching directory structure in `/usr/lib/firewalld` which provides the *defaults* for zones, services and icmptypes, in case you want to start customizing from a template, or simply see what the files look like.

The firewall configuration of the main services (ftp, httpd, etc) comes in the `/usr/lib/firewalld/services` directory. But it is still possible to add new ones in the `/etc/firewalld/services` directory. Also, if files exist at both locations for the same service, the file in the `/etc/firewalld/services` directory takes precedence.

Have great day future friend .! ;-)

Comment: If you're going to copy someone else's work word-for-word you should at least give credit https://serverfault.com/questions/655851/is-there-a-simple-way-to-export-import-firewalld-settings